# How to index string with underscore in Django with Haystack/Whoosh

Tags: django, django-haystack, whoosh

I am trying to implement search with Haystack and Whoosh in a Django project.

The `CharField` I am trying to index has data like `something_like_this`. But it won't show up in the search result if I search for 'something' or 'this. It only works if I search for 'something_like_this'. Is there anyway to search the keywords in the `CharFiled`?

All I can think of is to create another `CharField`, store the string without underscore of the original string and then index it. But that seems like stupid idea.

Answer (score 1):

Make `data_field` a `MultiValueField` and implement the `prepare_data_field` method where you could do something like this:

```
prepare_data_field(self, obj):
    return obj.data_field.split('_')
```